# How to disallow users to edit other's posts for a new custom post type?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, permissions

I am trying to add a new custom post type and everything works except one thing - contributors can edit other's post of this post type. Here is how I've registered it:

```
/**
 * Adding new "Series" post type
 */
function elegant_series_series_post_type() {
    // Set UI labels for custom post type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Series', 'Post Type General Name', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Series', 'Post Type Singular Name', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Series',elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    );

    // Set other options for custom post type
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'description'         => __( 'Post series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'rewrite'             => array('slug' => _x('series', 'Plural', elegant_series_config()['text_domain']))
    );

    $administer_series = "edit_others_posts";

    $args['capabilities'] = array(
        'edit_post'          => 'read',
        'read_post'          => 'read',
        'delete_post'        => 'read',
        'edit_posts'         => 'read',
        'edit_others_posts'  => $administer_series,
        'delete_posts'       => $administer_series,
        'publish_posts'      => $administer_series,
        'read_private_posts' => $administer_series,
        'create_posts'       => 'read',
        'edit_published_posts' => 'read',
        'edit_series'       => $administer_series,
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'series', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'elegant_series_series_post_type', 0 );
```

for some reason `'edit_others_posts'  => $administer_series,` does not work.

I've googled many things and played around with the capabilities, even asked `ChaptGPT` but nothing helped. Any ideas?